# Finding distance to a plane in a rotating system

Tags: math, geometry

I have this pre-school-level problem, I just don't know what direction to start, i'm pretty lame at math. Let me simplify my question through an example: We have a flying helicopter with a distance measuring equipment at the bottom, it is looking down. The ground is flat, the chopper can tilt forward and back and left or right. (can do both axes simultaneously) If the helicopter is completely in level my distance measure shows the altitude of the heli above the ground.
How to calculate the altitude with a given theta and phi tilt angles of the helicopter?
I have this feeling, it can be done by using simple 2D trigonometry, instead of 3D vector algebra to calculate line-plane intersections.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You need to give exactly the inputs available. Two angles are not enough information.  At least one more number is needed.  It's hard to t do computer graphics if you are "lame at math." You'll need to work on that :-)

Comment: I can make inputs available, please just name three of them =P

Comment: We may have a language barrier here. The specification for an algorithm starts with an exact description of the inputs and outputs. That's what you're missing. The language in the question is vague.

Comment: So, i have an infinite plane and a vector pointing at that plane, and i have both the magnitude and the relative angles of this vector (relative to the plane's normal), and you are saying that this projection can't be calculated with these params.

Comment: Grr, read it carefully,  I have the two angles and the absolute distance!

Answer (score 0):

I guess it would be:

```
altitude = D*cos(theta)*cos(phi)
```

Where D is the distance to the ground as measured from the helicopter?